# npm uninstall -g create-react-app Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

When creating a new react app with npx ( `npx create-react-app new_app --use-npm --template typescript`) I get the following error:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
```

Yet running `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` I get a permissions error:

```
npm WARN locking Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm WARN locking  C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock failed [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'] {
npm WARN locking   errno: -4048,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN locking   syscall: 'open',
npm WARN locking   path: 'C:\\Users\\MYCOMP~1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_locks\\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm WARN locking }
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\MYCOMP~1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_locks\\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
PS C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\seisolosite\newseisolosite\CSS3DDemo> npm uninstall -g create-react-app 
npm WARN locking Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm WARN locking  C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock failed [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'] {
npm WARN locking   errno: -4048,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN locking   syscall: 'open',
npm WARN locking   path: 'C:\\Users\\MYCOMP~1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_locks\\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm WARN locking }
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\MYCOMP~1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_locks\\staging-abfecabb8ac6a958.lock'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Running `yarn  uninstall -g create-react-app` works just fine:

```
yarn global v1.22.10
[1/2] Removing module create-react-app...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
warning "depcheck > @vue/compiler-sfc@3.1.5" has unmet peer dependency "vue@3.1.5".
success Uninstalled packages.
```

Ok great, so I should be set now, right??

But then I run  `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and get the same error, we `We no longer support global installation of Create React App.`. Restarting the computer and running the command in a new terminal does nothing. Retrying with yarn instead of npx doesn't work either, running  `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript` gives error:

```
'C:\Users\Primary' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So I'm pretty much completely stuck, with neither yarn or npx working with creat-react-app. Any clues on how to get one of them working?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Did you try run cmd with admin privilegies?

Comment: Run the command as administrator

Comment: Yes, this seems to have worked!