# How do I get over the spawn unknown error while running npx create-next-app . in vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, cmd, next.js

I keep getting a spawn unknown error when trying to create a next app on either vscode or cmd, which reads "Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN"

the installation aborts, am not sure what this error is or how to go about it.

Comment: Please do not post images, [Edit] your question, and submit the error information, as well as the commands/code we need to reproduce that, into individual code boxes instead.

Comment: okay, done. thanks, I just edited it. I have also gotten the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the antivirus (RAV) on my PC and it worked fine. Your antivirus might be different but uninstalling the antivirus solves it.

I got some help from this thread [npm uninstall -g create-react-app Error: EPERM: operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70796959/npm-uninstall-g-create-react-app-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).